# Vue - How to change dropdown text properly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have Vue drop-down.

```
 <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text= "UserName" class="m-md-2" >
       <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-link">Log out</b-dropdown-item>
 </b-dropdown>
```

I need t change value of drop down. In my case it's **UserName**

I only found this way:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown-1").childNodes[1].innerHTML="new value"
```

I know it's not correct way but I didn't find correct way (via the API or something like that). This method does not work too:

```
text= "{{ variable }}"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a dynamic value for `text` prop on `<b-dropdown>` and change it with the click event of `<b-dropdown-item>`

```html
<b-dropdown :text="buttonTitle">
   <b-dropdown-item @click="buttonTitle = 'new value'">Log out</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

```js
//script
data () {
  return {
    buttonTitle: 'Username'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `text` dynamic, you should [bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) it to a variable of your Vue component instance. An HTML attribute can be made dynamic and bound to a variable by using the `:` prefix before the attribute name (which is a shorthand of `v-bind:`)

Given :

```
<b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" :text="variable" class="m-md-2" >
   <b-dropdown-item class="dropdown-link">Log out</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

In the component you should have the corresponding `variable` declaration :

```
data() {
   return {
      variable: '' // Variable initialisation
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MuratK is probably right, however I understand that you want to bind the dropdown item, not the parent element. You could do so with a v-for and text binding, like:

```
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" class="m-md-2" >
      <b-dropdown-item v-for="item in items" v-text="item"></b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
```

Then, in your data define 'items' as an array of strings, such as ['log out', 'preferences', 'sign it']. You can also use this syntax, it does the same in your example:

```
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</b-dropdown-item>
```